# How to flatten nested lists when flatten function isn't working?

Tags: list-manipulation, output-formatting

I have a program that outputs values for T in the following nested list:

```
{{{T->3398}, {T->56706}, {T->1.1049x10^7}, {T->9.192x10^7}}, {{T->3379}, {T->54664}, 
{T->1.07x10^7}, {T->8.769x10^7}}, {{T->3353}, {T->52293}, {T->1.04x10^7}, {T->8.346x10^7}}}
```

I want to use these values to make a table and plot them, but I can't work with the data as it is right now because it is in these nested lists and attached to T with the right arrow.  I would like to be able to take the first value of T in each of the innermost lists, so 3398 3379 and 3353, but I am unable to do so.  I've tried the flatten function and tried to create a solution with the Map function but mathematica only returns this same list.  I should also note that my program runs a do loop 3 times to get those 3 innermost lists, and when I run the code after solving this problem I will run the do loop more times as I want to plot the first values as curves.

I should also note that in a separate file where I only run the do loop once I am able to flatten the list with a solution I found from another question.  I thought I could apply this solution to the above problem and then take the first values but I was unable to do so.  The problem is I need to run that do loop multiple times for my project so it doesn't help to be able to get the values for only running it once.

```
{{T->5416}, {T->1.532x10^6}, {T->3.85x10^6}, {T->1.399x10^8}}
list = %18
yay = {T} /. list
yayy = Flatten[yay]
ListPlot[yayy]
```

Can anybody help me to flatten the list so I can work with the values, specifically so I can grab the first T value from each innermost list? Any help is appreciated thank you!

Comment: Thank you for the answers this helps a lot

Comment: don’t forget to accept one of the answers! It is helpful for yourself and others to do such a thing, especially when one of the answers may be better or more useful to you than the others.

Answer (score 5):

With your data called tlist, you can write:

```
Flatten[tlist /. {Rule -> List, T -> Nothing}]
```

and it gives the list of values:

```
{3398, 56706, 1.1049 x10^7, 9.192 x10^7, 3379, 54664, 1.07 x10^7, 
       8.769 x10^7, 3353, 52293, 1.04 x10^7, 8.346 x10^7}
```

This changes the Rule (i.e, the arrow ->) into a List and then changes all the Ts into nothing, leaving only the numerical values. Then you can Flatten.

Answer (score 4):

Do you want this result?

```
list = {{{T -> 3398}, {T -> 56706}, {T -> 1.1049 x10^7}, {T -> 
      9.192 x10^7}}, {{T -> 3379}, {T -> 54664}, {T -> 
      1.07 x10^7}, {T -> 8.769 x10^7}}, {{T -> 3353}, {T -> 
      52293}, {T -> 1.04 x10^7}, {T -> 8.346 x10^7}}};
data = T /. list
data[[;; , 1]]
```

> `{3398, 3379, 3353}`

```
ListPlot[data[[;; , 1]]]
```

Answer (score 2):

One handy function when you're dealing with Rule expressions (that's what -> is) is Values:

```
orig = 
  {{{T -> 3398}, {T -> 56706}, {T -> 1.1049 x10^7}, {T -> 9.192 x10^7}}, 
   {{T -> 3379}, {T -> 54664}, {T -> 1.07 x10^7}, {T -> 8.769 x10^7}}, 
   {{T -> 3353}, {T -> 52293}, {T -> 1.04 x10^7}, {T -> 8.346 x10^7}}};
justVals = Values[orig]
```

`{{{3398}, {56706}, {1.1049*x10^7}, {9.192*x10^7}}, {{3379}, {54664}, {1.07*x10^7}, {8.769*x10^7}}, {{3353}, {52293}, {1.04*x10^7}, {8.346*x10^7}}}`

> I would like to be able to take the first value of T in each of the innermost lists, so 3398 3379 and 3353

You can use part to do this:

```
justVals[[1, All, 1, 1]]
```

`{3398, 3379, 3353}`

Now, that looks a bit weird, but it's just because your original list had a lot of extraneous levels.

Can't help much with the rest of your question without seeing your Do loop.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your data is called `tlist`:

```
tlist = {{{T -> 3398}, {T -> 56706}, {T -> 1.1049 x10^7}, {T -> 
     9.192 x10^7}}, {{T -> 3379}, {T -> 54664}, {T -> 
     1.07 x10^7}, {T -> 8.769 x10^7}}, {{T -> 3353}, {T -> 
     52293}, {T -> 1.04 x10^7}, {T -> 8.346 x10^7}}}
```

It is often difficult to visually see structure in lists when written out in a flat form. Try one or more of the following:

```
TreeForm[tlist]
```

or better still in this case:

```
tlist // TableForm
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 \{T\to 3398\} & \{T\to 56706\} & \left\{T\to 1.1049 \text{x10}^7\right\} & \left\{T\to 9.192 \text{x10}^7\right\} \\
 \{T\to 3379\} & \{T\to 54664\} & \left\{T\to 1.07 \text{x10}^7\right\} & \left\{T\to 8.769 \text{x10}^7\right\} \\
 \{T\to 3353\} & \{T\to 52293\} & \left\{T\to 1.04 \text{x10}^7\right\} & \left\{T\to 8.346 \text{x10}^7\right\} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

This is a a fairly regular array structure.

To get the first column you can use the following commands.

```
First /@ tlist
```

or

```
tlist[[All, 1]]
```

and finally:

```
First /@ tlist // Values // Flatten
```

> {3398, 3379, 3353}